# How to extract the parameters of a method like string using regular expressions?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a method like signature that looks like this:

```
void methodName(str arg1, int arg2, int arg3 = 4)
{
}
```

or

```
str methodName2(int arg1)
{
}
```

I want to extract only the parameters of this to give

```
(str arg1, int arg2, int arg3 = 4)
(int arg1)
```

Here is what I have tried. This never matches for me.

```
string namePortion = String.Format(@"^.*{0}", "methodName");

Regex rex = new Regex(namePortion + @"\s*(?<params>\(.*\)).*\{", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline);
string parms = "";

Match m = rex.Match(sourceCode);

if (m.Success)
{
    parms = m.Groups["params"].Value;
}
```

I have also tested this out in RegexBuddy, and it seems to work, so I am not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going VERY broad, the following should work for you:

```
(?:^|[\r\n])[\w\s]*(?<params>\(.*?\))
```

To just grab prototypes (and use brace as a delimiter):

```
(?:^|[\r\n])[\w\s]*(?<params>\(.*?\)).*?\{
```

If you're looking for something more specific, let me know.

**EDIT** Added `(?:^|[\r\n])` which makes sure it's at the start of the file or line.

Comment: In the brace one, remove the ungreedy `?` from inside of the params group. This will make it hard-match the parenthesis-immediate-brace and not leave anything out. (Although it [seems to work for me](http://regexr.com?2su3h))

Answer (score 0):

Try to change Multiline to Singleline

Comment: Method declarations, esp. those with many parameters, can and often do span multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

I think this regex parses out each param individually, but I can't test it at the moment so use it at your own risk. You will need to add a global flag to your `Regex` object for it to match more than one parameter and its also a single-line regex, so you'll need to match against each individual line in your source.

`String regex = "^[\s]*methodName[\s]*\\((?<param>[^,\\)]*)*\\).*?$";`

Reading this regex: At the beginning of the line (`^`) match any number of spaces (`[\s]*`), then the string literal "methodName" (`methodName`), then any number of spaces again (`[\s]*`), then an open parenthesis (`\\(`), then start a capture group called "param" (`(?<param>`), then match any number of anything that isn't a comma or closing-parenthesis (`[^,\\)]*`), then close the "param" capture group and match that group any number of times (`)*`), then finally match a closed parenthesis, any character (lazy), and the end of the line (`\\).*?$`)